# How to dynamically add directive to html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that opens a popup "". A user can click "Never show this gain" which will store a cookie and next time the popup won't show.
The problem is that I don't want to the directive to always render in the html unless needed. At the moment I'm just doing something like

```
$("#popups-container").html($compile("<my-popup></my-popup>")($scope))
```

but this doesn't feel right.

Is there any "angular way" to do it ?

Comment: I found myself having to do a `$compile` in some code lately. In that case, I was repeatedly attaching and detaching a DOM element, depending on user interaction, which is a different use-case. I assume your directive checks for the presence of the cookie - can you use this to hide the directive itself, maybe using `ng-show` or `ng-hide` on the directive's template? It might help to post some of your directive code.

Comment: `ng-show` and `ng-hide` do not prevent the compilation of the directive itself. They just add: `display:none`.

Comment: True, but I wasn't suggesting that it did. I was thinking more along the lines of showing or hiding html within the directive's template, depending on the cookie's setting, not avoiding compilation. For the record `ng-switch` is a good suggestion +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `ng-switch`. Depending on the value you can use `ng-switch-when` to dynamically declare what parts of your html should be compiled. More info [HERE](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch).

Comment: I think this is the right answer, didn't get the chance to test it but from the documentation it seems it does what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your directive 'myPopup',
Check if the cookie is present or not. if cookie is present do
element.remove();
else
compile and return your html

Comment: Doing so will still compile the directive.